# get video id from new youtu.be urls

Tags: php, youtube

I have the following code that grabs youtube's video id from the old share urls (youtube.com/watch?v=adasdalkjsd)

```
        $url = $_GET['url']; 
        parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $query); 
        $video_id = isset($query['v']) ? $query['v'] : NULL;
```

that works for the old ones but i need a system that can work for both urls. any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URLs are for example: http://youtu.be/QzEcJecXJC4?hd=1

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$video_id = substr( parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), 1 );
```

See [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). PHP_URL_PATH will give you `/QzEcJecXJC4`, so you need to use `substr` to cut out the slash.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using `ltrim` vs `substr`?