# Get youtube video ID from a dynamically generated youtu.be link

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, youtube

I'm working with a WordPress plugin that outputs a text link, but the user inputs the link from an 3rd party site. the links are youtu.be format, I need the video's ID. [I have tried this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899949/get-video-id-from-new-youtu-be-urls) but I'm not getting it so far

**original code:**

```
  if($video_link != "")     {   

echo '<p>';         
echo 'Please visit : <a href="'. $video_link .'"> Multimedia link </a> for more photos and information' ;
echo '</p>';        
    }
```

**Output link :**

http://youtu.be/abcdefghijkl

**tried this, can't get it to work:**

```
if($video_link != "")
        {   

    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $video_id = substr( parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), 1 );                                         
echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed'.$video_id.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' ;    
}
```

**Output Iframe does not work  :**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Ignore my previous answer, your parse works fine. You just forgot the `/` after 'embed' in your iframe src attribute.

Or if you want, you can just remove the `substr` part in your parse (which is what strips the slash)

```
$video_id = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Comment: Thank you Kunruh! I only had to make one change I changed parse_url($url  to $video_id = substr( parse_url($video_link, PHP_URL_PATH), 1 );

Comment: would it be possible to see if the link contains one kind of link or another? like this? if(strpos($video_link, 'https://youtu.be/') !== TRUE)  @kunruh